# JavaFX Weird Border Issue With GridPane

Tags: javafx-8

I'm having a minor issue with the borders of my grid pane. The grid pane is 10x10 and contains rectangles.

The rectangles in the grid have 3 states: inactive (white), active (gray) and enabled (random color).

The grid pane has setGridLinesVisible set to false and the rectangles have white borders as to make it seem like only the active and enabled rectangles are inside the grid.

This works perfectly but I'm getting some weird effect where the borders extend to the end of the grid pane as seen in the following screenshot:
[image]

Is there a way to remove these grey lines?

Thanks!

EDIT: this his how the rectangles are added to the grid pane:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            StackPane guidePane = new StackPane();
            Label l = new Label();
            l.setTextFill(Color.WHITE);
            Rectangle b = new Rectangle();
            guidePane.getChildren().add(b);
            guidePane.getChildren().add(l);
            ourGrid.add(guidePane, i, j); << this is the GridPane
            blockArray[i][j] = guidePane;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could be the color "behind" the grid (scene color/gridpane or parent's background color). Check, if modifying the grid's background color (e.g. using `ourGrid.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white;");`) fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solution removed from question body:

> You have to set the stroke color for the rectangles with `b.setStroke(Color.WHITE);` to get rid of the grey lines.